# Inflating List view with Linear Layout, text view not getting match parent

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have a list view which is inflated with a linear layout containing six text view. I want the width of inflated text view to be match parent but its width is getting set according to value I am getting from database(Getting wrapped). I have given equal weights to textview in linear layout but width of all the textviews are different. Values of text view are coming from database using JDBC connection.

List view layout is:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#0dcd6600"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
    </ListView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And that of row inflated in list view is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="6" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border1"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_sname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border1"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_standard"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border1"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_division"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border1"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_grno"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border1"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_rollno"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border1"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So far I have tried all the below options, nothing worked.

1. Changing **view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_attendance,null);**

    to

    **view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_attendance, parent, false);**
2. Making List view's width to match_parent
3. Making six linear layout for all text view and making them match parent.

Here is the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o11xR.png) of the layout which is not proper. Text fields are not getting aligned.

And how I want it to be is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Putbm.png).

Comment: try to use table layout

Comment: Try to use Table Layout, so that width of Textviews are divided equally.

Comment: But the same layout of list view is being used in other activities to view reports and I have about 15 activities which I cannot change it in one day.. I have deadline.. Any other options of making it proper? @Arvindlal Jaiswal

Comment: I got confused with this part -- ***I want to width of inflated text view to be match parent but its width is getting set according to value set in it.*** Do you mean that, the width of the TextViews should be long enough equal to the parent?  Or do you mean that each TextView would have equal size in width? -- along that it would still be able to scroll horizontally?

Comment: if you don't set any text to your textview. did it display correct

Comment: @sept In the image that i have attached, the text view with value 'NURSERY' is bigger and the text view with value "LKG" is smaller.. due to this they are not getting aligned vertically.. I want both of them to be of same width regardless of the text value in it.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh If their is no text in it then all the text view are of same width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to listview in HorizontalScrollView. Weightsum and weight does not work if list view is in horizontal scroll view..

Comment: But the reports cannot be seen properly without Horizontal scroll.. Don't we have any other option to get it perfect.? @Ashlesha Sharma

Comment: Recycler view perfectly suits your problem,try it!

Comment: After trying all the solutions which I knew, I found that weightsum and weights does not work if we have set list view in horizontal scroll view.. Removing it gives equal weigh to all text view..

Comment: I couldn't find the solution to make it aligned using this method only.. But at least now I know the problem in it.. So your answer is correct.. Thanks.. @Ashlesha Sharma

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution but i think you are wrong here. Don't use scrollview as a parent. Please try this once. Hope it will work.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had this before but removed it as i felt this relative or linear layout would be the problem. It doesn't work..